# How to rebuild the full transaction CPIs details and depth from a single source?

Tags: jsonrpc-api

The transaction meta does not allow rebuilding the exact nesting of CPIs for a given transaction, while it associates inner instructions to a given top level ix.

Is there a valid reason it is so? Is there a way to surface the data without resorting to log parsing (which can be truncated)?

An example transaction, Jupiter V4 https://explorer.solana.com/tx/2F4extgNL9HgvHyTBQtFdDtiJd8f1cUEp1qQxA3Y4UQhzyqTfkgqmRL9DFTHLUh1zeeunRdaZxyuhEfwZuH5WStv

the token transfers should be CPIs from each swap program but they are flattened.

[image: parseProgramLogs render in the explorer]

An example how the explorer achieves it with `parseProgramLogs`, resorting to log parsing to provide the necessary identification

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/06ffd9009e67eb054b9ffbb2166e0fd25380d204/explorer/src/utils/program-logs.ts#L20-L166

Comment: Is this just an explorer thing? In program logs that are returned by tests it usually has a [1], [2], [3] numbering system to indicate depth of CPI calls

Comment: The numbering is pointing to which top level ix it belongs, someone checked with Justin and there is effectively no way other than the smelly log parsing right now.

Comment: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/27736 should help you eventually!